# how to use subprocess to run a virtualenv package install

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I am writing a bootstrap code for one of my programs, and trying to install to my virtualenv directory using subprocess.call

initially I used :

```
subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', '-E', dir_name, 'processing'])
```

When re-running on ubuntu I noticed that the -E was outdated (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/) and need to use:

```
virtualenv dir_name && dir_name/bin/pip install processing
```

This works fine from the cmd line but will not work in subprocess:

```
subprocess.call(['virtualenv', dir_name, '&&', '{0}/bin/pip'.format(dir_name), 'install', 'processing'])
```

Returns this error message:

```
There must be only one argument: DEST_DIR (you gave dir_name && dir_name/bin/pip install   processing)
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR
```

I have also tried virtualenv.create_bootstrap_script(extra_text) (but can not figure it out and have some additional scripts I am running that are from git)

Wondering what I am doing wrong in subprocess or what I can change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the status of the first command, then conditionally run the second:

```
retval = subprocess.call(
    ['virtualenv', dir_name]
)
if retval == 0:
    # a 0 return code indicates success
    retval = subprocess.call(
        ['{0}/bin/pip'.format(dir_name), 'install', 'processing']
    )
    if retval == 0:
        print "ERROR: Failed to install package 'processing'"
else:
    print "ERROR: Failed to created virtualenv properly."
```

**Warning: danger below!**

In order for the `&&` token to work, you must use the argument shell=True in `subprocess.call`. However, you **MUST NOT** use shell=True if you're accepting input from the user, because it will then allow arbitrary code execution.

Additionally, you need to join the args together.

If you're using a dir_name that you are hard coding:

```
cmdline = ' '.join(['virtualenv', dir_name, '&&', '{0}/bin/pip'.format(dir_name), 'install', 'processing'])
subprocess.call(
    cmdline,
    shell=True
)
```

Comment: Thanks! subprocess.call(['{0}/bin/pip'.format(dir_name), 'install', 'processing']) works!

Comment: sorry I hit enter before i could type everything out and fix my edit